# SQL Server 2005 Unable to Create Relationship Because it's Conflicting with itself(?)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Consider the following tables (unnecessary fields have been omitted) and the relationships I'm trying to create:

```
 Contractor__c               |Task                 |Account
|----------------------------|---------------------|---------------|
|Contractor__c NCHAR(18) NULL|WhatId NCHAR(18) NULL|Id NCHAR(18) PK|
|Id            NCHAR(18) PK  |                     |               |

 FK_Contractor__c_Account
|--------------------------------------|
|PK        |FK                         |
|----------|---------------------------|
|Account.Id|Contractor__c.Contractor__c|

 FK_Task_Contractor__c
|----------------------------|
|PK              |FK         |
|----------------|-----------|
|Contractor__c.Id|Task.WhatId|
```

Sounds and looks simple enough, but both of the relationships fail to save to the database and I get the following errors for both:

> Unable to create relationship 'FK_Contractor__c_Account'.   The ALTER
>   TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_Contractor__c_Account". The conflict occurred in database
>   "Contractors", table "dbo.Account", column 'Id'.
>
> Unable to create relationship 'FK_Task_Contractor__c'.   The ALTER
>   TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_Task_Contractor_*c". The conflict occurred in database
>   "Contractors", table "dbo.Contractor*_c", column 'Id'.

I'm understanding the messages as it being unable to create the relationship because its conflicting with a relationship that has the same name that exists, even though in reality there isn't one. Can someone enlighten me on what's going on here?

For anyone who cares, I'm using SQL Server 2005 SP4 (9.0.5057) and the tables are created from a Salesforce linked server using DBAmp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message means that some of the data does not satisfy the constraint. It does not mean that some schema-based conflict has occurred.

Comment: I was kind of thinking that too. Is it because some of the columns are nullable?

Comment: FKs skip null values. Write a left join query to find out what data is not being matched.

Comment: Well, I did a LEFT JOIN and a JOIN between the tables in the relationships both normal and reversed. Not one erred out, so I'm still stuck trying to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: In the end there was missing data from Salesforce. I've given up on trying to establish relationships.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem... I went into my main table and found a 0 id in three tables that fed dropdownlists... I changed the 0s to a value in the table and wala... no further problems...